# Filter pandas dataframe by several time periods?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I have a timestamp column (originally string values converted using pd.to_datetime), sorted it, and set as the index. I am looking to filter the dataframe through this index to remove all rows that aren't included in a given set of time periods.

Example time periods would be (format is %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f if it matters):

```
10/05/2020 13:14:40.980 to 10/05/2020 21:50:52.323  
10/06/2020 06:45:31.839 to 10/06/2020 17:05:11.382  
10/06/2020 22:10:05.872 to 10/07/2020 07:03:52.872  
etc....
```

I have found that `df.between_time(*pd.to_datetime(['10/05/2020 13:14:40.980', '10/06/2020 21:50:52.323']).time)` works for selecting a single time period, but how would I do this for selecting multiple periods at once? Can between_time be used this way? Would I need to make a reference dictionary to pair off the start/end times of the different time periods?

Also, counting the number of rows being excluded from the total when conducting this filtering step would be helpful to know.

Thank you for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Just use boolean conditions, with '&' between time periods.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(data=1, index=pd.date_range("2019-1-1", "2019-5-1"))
df.loc[(df.index < pd.to_datetime("2019-1-8")) | ((df.index > pd.to_datetime("2019-4-22")) & (df.index < pd.to_datetime("2019-4-25")))]
```

results:

```
2019-01-01    1
2019-01-02    1
2019-01-03    1
2019-01-04    1
2019-01-05    1
2019-01-06    1
2019-01-07    1
2019-04-23    1
2019-04-24    1
dtype: int64
```

here I filtered dates between 22/4/2019 to 25/4/2019 with dates smaller (8/1/2019) (those dates format in "dd/mm/yyyy", while in code my format is "yyyy-mm-dd"). It will work the same with time